# Is it possible to create an array of math operators in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a programme that involves using an array of math operators which can be added to a equation to make it perform the operation in VB.net however I cannot seem to get the operators into an array or list of any type and how to implement them into equations as shown below.

```
Dim Operators As String = {+, -, *, /}
For i = 0 to Operators.Length - 1
    Console.Write(1 Operators(i) 2)
Next
```

Output should be: 3, -1, 2, 0.5

However I run into an error when trying to run this. Any advice on how to make an array of math operators and then use it to add numbers is helpful.

Comment: First thing I would suggest is to turn Option Strict On.  Next, if storing the operators of strings you will need to read the string content, then take some action base on that content (If "+" then a + b etc).  Maybe you could do a List of Functions to preform your operations?

Comment: It's also pretty helpful when you do encounter errors, to tell us what they are, were they are uncounted and what you've done to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way.

turns out there is a "expression" evaluator in the table object.

So, this will work:

```
    Dim tbl = New DataTable()
    Dim Operators() As String = {"+", "-", "*", "/"}
    For Each sOP As String In Operators
        Debug.Print(tbl.Compute($"1 {sOP}  2", Nothing))
    Next
```

(I used debug.print - windows form in place of console).

output:

```
3
-1
2
0.5
```

Or, maybe a bit "pretty" like this:

```
    Dim tbl = New DataTable()
    Dim Operators() As String = {"+", "-", "*", "/"}
    Dim sCalc As String = ""
    For Each sOP As String In Operators
        sCalc = $"1 {sOP}  2"
        Debug.Print($"{sCalc} = {tbl.Compute(sCalc, Nothing)}")
    Next
```

output:

```
1 +  2 = 3
1 -  2 = -1
1 *  2 = 2
1 /  2 = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in translating the Operator string value in to something the program can execute. This is best done in either an `If...Else` type of statement or a `Select...Case` statement.

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub TestMethod1()
    Dim Operators() As String = {"+", "-", "*", "/"}

    For Each op In Operators
        Debug.WriteLine(Operation(op, 1, 2))
    Next
End Sub

Public Function Operation(op As String, val1 As Int32, val2 As Int32) As Decimal
    Select Case op
        Case "+"
            Return val1 + val2

        Case "-"
            Return val1 - val2

        Case "*"
            Return val1 * val2

        Case "/"
            Return CDec(val1 / val2)
    End Select

    Return 0
End Function
```

This produces your desired results of `3, -1, 2, 0.5`

It is limited in that this version will only work with Integers.